# Lebesgue/Jordan null set

Tags: measure-theory

I can't understand, what is the difference between Lebesgue and Jordan null set?

As far as I understand, it is some set, which contains nothing, but so what, what is the joy?

Comment: In one case it is Lebesgue measure $0$, in the other Jordan "measure" $0$. For each of the notions, there are non-empty sets of $0$ measure.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$ is Lebesgue null but it contains something, and quite a lot of something, might I say. The "joy" when working with measure theory is that you can "ignore" null measure set's influence on the grander scheme of things. Since probability is any finite measure, that's why you can "ignore" the exceptions to the rule when working with statistics, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Lebesgue measure is a way of assigning a non-negative number (possibly $\infty$) to a large collection of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ in a sensible way. In particular, if $\mathcal{A}$ is the collection of suitable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e. the Lebesgue measurable subsets), then the Lebesgue measure $m$ satisfies:

- $m(A) \geq 0$ for all $A \in \mathcal{A}$,
- $m(\emptyset) = 0$,
- $m\left(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i\right) = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}m(A_i)$ for any collection of pairwise disjoint sets $A_i \in \mathcal{A}$, and
- $m([0,1]) = 1$.

The first three conditions are what is required for $m$ to be a *measure*, and the final condition ensures that the Lebesgue measure extends the notion that the measure of an interval is its length.

With this definition, there are plenty of sets which have Lebesgue measure zero: all countable sets and the Cantor set are some examples. In particular, there are lots of Lebesgue null sets (sets with Lebesgue measure zero) which are not empty.

One reason why null sets are important is that a lot of constructions in measure theory, in particular the Lebesgue integral, are defined up to changes on null sets (what is commonly referred to as *almost everywhere* and abbreviated as a.e.). So if we are evaluating the Lebesgue integral of a function $f$, we can effectively ignore the values of $f$ on any Lebesgue null set.

**Example:** Consider the indicator function of $\mathbb{Q}$:

$$\chi_{\mathbb{Q}}(x) = \begin{cases}
1 &\ \text{if}\ x \in \mathbb{Q}\\
0 &\ \text{if}\ x \not\in \mathbb{Q}.
\end{cases}$$

Outside of the Lebesgue null set $\mathbb{Q}$, $\chi_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is equal to $0$. As we can ignore the values of a function on a Lebesgue null set when calculating its Lebesgue integral we have

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\chi_{\mathbb{Q}}\ dm = \int_{\mathbb{R}}0\ dm = 0.$$

This example is of particular interest because $\chi_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is Lebesgue integrable but not Riemann integrable.

The Jordan measure is a restriction of the Lebesgue measure to a smaller collection of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. In particular, every Jordan null set is a Lebesgue null set, but the converse is not true. For example, $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ is a Lebesgue null set (it is countable), but it is not Jordan measurable so it can't be Jordan null. Despite the name, Jordan measure is not a genuine measure.